# How come they use gehen + dative preposition?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, dative, accusative

Ich gehe zur Arbeit

Ich gehe zur Schule

Ich gehe zum Strand

Ich gehe in die Kirche

Ich gehe ins Einkaufszentrum

Ich gehe in die Berge

Ich gehe ins Büro

I thought that for verbs of movement like gehen, accusative should be used. While the last 4 sentences agree with this, the first three sentences are using dative, why? Isn't zu a two-way preposition?

Comment: You already know all of the necessary concepts, and indeed “zu” is not a two-way preposition.

Comment: @CarstenS So zu takes only dative? If that is so, does the case a preposition takes have precedence over the rule that movement verbs should use the accusative?

Comment: That rule is for two-way prepositions only, that’s why they form a class worth having a name. Whenever there is a preposition, it determines the case. It’s just that those ten (according to my first google result) prepositions can go both ways, depending on meaning.

Comment: "Ich gehe kaputt" fehlt noch. ;)